# Repetitive data in WordPress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a tutorial site for music producers. On each tutorial (post, that is) there will be some information that are repetitive and recurring, so I was wondering what's the best practice to enter this data while creating a post to later being able to present it in the post?

This is an example, where the data is bold and labels in plain:
Requirements: Steinberg Cubase, ProTools (an array)
Estimated time: 1 hour (string)
Project files: File 1, File 2 (files)

Any good plug-ins or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about build-in custom fields functionality?

Comment: I think that's kind of messy to work with. You'll have to know all the name of each fields etc.

Comment: get_post_custom() function returns all custom fileds data in array, you can display all data using foreach without knowing all names of each fileds, or i'm incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I guess custom fields is the way to go like anyrat said

can't think of another way - so i "up"ed his answer

Let me know if u found another way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to format the data in a special way, and you are entering unique data as your enter each post then, I would enter the data in custom fields, and then use a custom post type to display it. It's quite neat.

If the data is the same for every post, then just edit your single post (and possibly category, main index, etc) theme file to add this data.

Since you mention arrays and such, you might be talking about having selectable data to add as you are writing posts? The best solution I know of for this is [PodsCMS](http://podscms.org)